# ¿Como hacer mas chico el texto si es mas grande que el div?

Tags: css, html5, css3, div, font-size

Trato de hacer que si el texto es mas grande (osea que es más largo y casi como para salirse del div) entonces en lugar de salirse, el font size del texto cambie a un valor donde sea lo suficientemente más chico para que se vea toda la palabra seguida, dentro del div, el texto de la palabra es un texto que cambia constantemente y si cambia a una palabra que es más grande que el div.

Me pasa esto:

[image: La palabra se sale del div y no esta centrado devido a eso]

Quiero que suceda esto:

[image: La palabra se hace más pequeña para que toda pueda caber en el div]

Este es el código:

HTML

```
<div>
   <h1 class="palabra">palabraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.palabra{
    color:#2a007d;
    font-family: "Comics";
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

Ojo: conozco la propiedad word-wrap: break-word; Pero no me gusta ya la probe y no es lo que estoy buscando, me gustaria que si alguien sabe que el texto se haga mas chico dependiendo del tamaño del div me diga como. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Entonces buscas una función que encoja el texto hasta el tamaño del div ?? pero hay limites en eso. Por ejemplo, hasta que tamaño poder verlo, y que sea legible, por que el texto se seguirá estirando hasta no verse ?? Y que harás con resto ?? Hay que usar overflow de todos modos.

Comment: quieres poner un scroll?

Comment: Hay varias soluciones en función del caso. Deja un enlace o pon unos pantallazos de como estás resolviendo el responsive. Que se vea todo el conjunto de los elementos y te podré sugerir la mejor solución para tu problema.